# Как выполнять действия с элементами массива переданным с php в js?

Tags: php, javascript, массивы

Вот массив в `php`

```
$content = array('time' => $time, 'user' => $user, 'message'  => $message);
```

Если запрос AJAX на эту странницу успешен то в файле с `php` выводиться

```
print_r($content);
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var text = $('#text').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'php/chat_script.php',
            data : {
                message:text
            },
            success: function(arr) {
                arr = JSON.parse(arr);
                $('#time').html(arr.time);
                $('#user').html(arr.user);
                $('#message').html(arr.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Мне например нужно вывести в HTML таблицу это всё так: `time` в `<td id="time"></td>`,`user` в `<td id="time"></td>` и `message` в `<td id="message"></td>`.Как это сделать?

Массив имеет вид:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [time] => 16:20:11
        [user] => qwe
        [message] => qwe
    )

)
```

Comment: тебе не нужно распечатать результаты, а его передавать в виде json, который в случае успеха обработать на фронте

Comment: @ВасильБоднарук да печатал я их что бы глянуть как оно выглядит. А зачем в json передавать?

Comment: пото что в нельзя ajax с php передавать дание в виде масива, а json ето строка которую можна передать и потом на стороне js, можна преобразовать обратно в масив, сейчас напишу код, используеш jquery?

Comment: @ВасильБоднарук да, конечно)

Answer (score 0):

php:

```
$content = array('time' => $time, 'user' => $user, 'message'  => $message);
echo json_encode($content);
```

axajx

```
success: function(arr) {
arr = JSON.parse(arr);
$('#time').html(arr.time);
$('#user').html(arr.user);
$('#message').html(arr.message);
}
```

Comment: У меня js запускается после нажатия на кнопку и я не знаю почему, но когда  я нажимаю на неё, оно вроде на долю секунды выводиться и исчезает, а страница обновляется и все поля пустые.

Comment: @Mbmenes функция которая срабатывает при клику имеет только ajax запрос?

Comment: Добавил  код запроса в вопрос.